# C#.NET Regex: need help on writing group expression with exclusions

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group

I am not an expert but I am trying to write .NET regex expression to exclude SQL comment lines. Unfortunately I cannot find a proper description of how to use exclusion groups to find regex matches on another regex match: ('.*?')  .

This regex finds all text between quotes but it also includes SQL comment areas (/*..*/ and --..):

```
'.*?'
```

Everything I tried it does not work as I am expecting.

My test sample:

```
    IF @RetValue = 'Cat'
   /*SET @RetValue = 'WrongLocation
and it works here' */
   ------testing line
SET @Dude = 'Punto'
/* comments */
    -- But it doesn't work here because inside comments! 
    -- and this is aren't the end
    SET @RetValue = 'But this should
work here'
```

Correct match should return only this:

```
'Cat'
''Punto'
and
'But this should
work here'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find an elegant RegEx to do what you want in one step, but you can do it in two steps.

```
string commentFree = Regex.Replace(sourceString, @"\/\*.*?\*\/|\-\-[^\n]*\n", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Now you can run the RegEx `'[^']*'` on commentFree to extract your fields.

Note that `'[^']*'` is more efficient than `'.*?'`, because it removes the need for the RegEx engine to backtrack.  Now it'll find the start quote, continue for all characters that themselves aren't a quote, and finish with the end quote.  The same technique is used above to grab the comment after `--` until the end of the line `\n`.

**Edit:**  Alternately, you can use the pattern `\/\*.*?\*\/|\-\-[^\n]*\n|'[^']*'` to match all comments and quote blocks (that are not within comments), and then only use the matches that begin with `'` when iterating through the results, as those will be the quote blocks.

Comment: The pattern you offered does not work on example as I've expected so stuck on replacing comments to spaces as I still need processing of data further. This is best solution for now as now one offered better other patterns and the one which I have has some issues as well.